# Is there any way similar to <img> to display contents of a .txt file

Tags: javascript, html, image, text-files

I have some HTML and JavaScript code, that implements a slide show for a set of images. Now I'd like to include .txt files.

Is there anything in HTML or JavaScript that I can use to implement the same? I do not want to use anything outside of HTML and JavaScript.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This would do the job

```
<iframe src="yourtext.txt"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks pal, I knew this was going to be a finger race

Answer (score 4):

Use XMLHttpRequest to pull down the text file, and insert it into a div or the like.  Although you can use an iframe, you have very little control over the appearance....for instance most browsers won't even wrap lines.  The downside of xmlhttprequest is that it must come from the same server as the html file.

Here is a simple function to make using XHR a bit easier:

```
function getFile (url) {
  var request = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0");
  request.open("GET", url, true);
  request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
        if (request.status == 200) {
          if (request.responseText) {

            // do stuff here


            }
        }
      else {
        // handle error
      }
    };
  request.send(null);
}
```

Comment: Voteup: just because you didn't use jQuery.

Comment: A note for passersby: This solution will only work if you're pulling from the same domain. If you need to pull from other domains, use the `iframe` solution.

Answer (score 3):

You could try an `iframe`.

Answer (score 3):

You can load a text file into an IFRAME element...

```
<iframe src="foo.txt"></iframe>
```